# sample project associated with Pro Business Applications with Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0

Pro Business Applications with Silverlight 4 mentions that it has an associated sample project.  Anyone know where I can get the sample project?

Thanks much.

Answer (score 1):

All the sample code for the book can be found here: http://www.apress.com/book/downloadfile/4638.

Hope this helps...

Chris

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: I saw the previous answer is not up to date anymore. I found the source code for the sample projects on this page: http://www.apress.com/web-development/silverlight/9781430272076